Find all links in text
I want to find all the links in text. For example, with this input:
foo [https://www.example.com/link1](https://www.example.com/link2) data
bar https://www.example.com/link3?test[0]=val data data
xyz https://www.example.com/link4] test foo
https://www.example.com/link5

I want to get following links:
https://www.example.com/link1
https://www.example.com/link2
https://www.example.com/link3?test[0]=val
https://www.example.com/link4
https://www.example.com/link5

I managed to create this regex:
(http[s]*:\/\/((?!\s|(?<!\[\d)\]|\)).)*)

But I have additional group in match, what I would like to avoid. What should I do to limit group to only 1?
https://regex101.com/r/Jtb8bc/1

Try it like this \bhttps:\/\/[^][()\s]*(?:\[[^][\s]*\][^][\s]*)* https://regex101.com/r/0CsUY4/1

Or if you only want to match digits between the square brackets \bhttps?://[^][()\s]*(?:\[\d+][^][\s]*)* https://regex101.com/r/doiURT/1

@Thefourthbird great! it works. Last thing - how can I cover this case: https://www.example.com/link1https://www.example.com/link2. I would like to get 2 links of this

@Thefourthbird It does cover this case: https://www.example.com/link1https://www.example.com/link2, but it doesn't cover this: https://test.pl?test[0]=valhttps://test.pl?test[0]=val

That could have some unexpected matches, what if the string has test[0]=http://www.test

@Thefourthbird I assume the https:// part marks the beginning of a new link. I came with this: https://regex101.com/r/yPnlnh/1 but it seems to be very slow

Perhaps like this https?://(?:(?!https?://)[^][\s](?:\[\d+])*)* https://regex101.com/r/xl6g3s/1

Did that one work out?

Does this answer your question? Regular expression to find URLs within a string

@yivi That page is not a suitable duplicate for this specific question.

You could use:
https?://(?:(?!https?://)[^][\s](?:\[\d+])*)*

The pattern matches:

https?:// Match the protocol with optional s followed by ://
(?: Non capture group to repeat as a whole

(?!https?://) Negative lookahead, assert what is drectly to the right is not http:// or https://
[^][\s] Match a non whitespace character other than [ ]
(?:\[\d+])* Optionlly repeat [ 1+ digits and ]


)* Close the non capture group and repeat is 0 or more times

See a regex demo.

@bobblebubble Hi there! I think that for JavaScript this syntax will also work right? https://regex101.com/r/I0w08l/1

Your Regex should be:
https\:\/\/w{3}[\.\w+]+(\/\w+)+(\?[\w\[\]\=]+)?


JavaScript Solution:


const arr = [
   'foo [https://www.example.com/link1](https://www.example.com/link2) data',
   'bar https://www.example.com/link3?test[0]=val data data',
   'xyz https://www.example.com/link4] test foo',
   'https://www.example.com/link5'
];

console.log(arr.map(x => x.match(/https\:\/\/w{3}[\.\w+]+(\/\w+)+(\?[\w\[\]\=]+)?/gi)));




Your last requirements is: 

According to my understand, you want to match the first occurrence only.
In every programming language when we match a pattern, it return an array of substring. If you run the above code you see the similar result.
So, after return the matching pattern capture the 1st element only.
Example for JavaScript Solution:


const arr = [
   'foo [https://www.example.com/link1](https://www.example.com/link2) data',
   'bar https://www.example.com/link3?test[0]=val data data',
   'xyz https://www.example.com/link4] test foo',
   'https://www.example.com/link5'
];

console.log(arr.map(x => x.match(/https\:\/\/w{3}[\.\w+]+(\/\w+)+(\?[\w\[\]\=]+)?/gi)[0]));



